# startActivityForResult in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have this code inside my MainActivity:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView=null;
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1){
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                final Button newProdButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.new_prod_button);
                newProdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), NewProdActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult (intent, OK_NEW_PRODUCT);
                        }

                });
```

And after it:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        if (requestCode==OK_NEW_PRODUCT){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
              Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ProductActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);

           }
        } 
      }
```

The purpose is to start a second activity at the end of the first, in case the latter has successfully performed all the operations.

However, when I end the first task, nothing happens and the application remains on the `MainActivity`. Why?

Comment: have you tried =>resultCode == RESULT_OK instead of resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ?

Comment: add some log in onActivityResult method to certain the program has running when finshed the first activity.if not,please certain call setResult method when finish the first activity.

Comment: Lemme ask you something just for confirmation, are you sure your first activity is an activity and not a fragment?

Comment: i think it is a fragment

Comment: @Simone11489 : Please let us know if it is a fragment i.e if it extends `Activity` class or `Fragment` class?

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of `requestCode` and `resultCode` when `onActivityResult` is reached.
Indeed, if the first Activity doesn't call `setResult(RESULT_OK)`, android will return `RESULT_CANCELED` for you, and the second startActivity call will never be reached.

Comment: The same value  OK_NEW_PRODUCT=0

Comment: Likely you are receiving `RESULT_CANCELED`. if you aren't explicitly calling `SetResult(RESULT_OK)`, Android will set `RESULT_CANCELED` for you.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer, @HappyCactus, to include the information from your comment? As a standalone answer, it's just a comment (and is a candidate for being deleted).

Comment: @ChrisForrence thanks, done

Just a blind shot: remove the super.onActivityResult call. It should not be the problem, but it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `setResult(RESULT_OK)` before finishing the first activity

Comment: Done: in the other activity I have:
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();

Comment: if you're referring to eclipse logs it does not give me back nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your code of `MainActivity` suggests that it is a fragment. If it is so, then use:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult (intent, OK_NEW_PRODUCT);
```

instead of:

```
startActivityForResult (intent, OK_NEW_PRODUCT);
```

Comment: The code which you have posted here for `MainActivity` contains `getActivity()`.Doesn't it?Are you sure the code which you posted is the exact same one what you have in your eclipse?

Comment: wrong answer?What do you mean by that?If you solved it and posted your answer which worked for you then accept that answer i.e click on the "right mark" below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem writing the code in the following way:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult (intent, OK_NEW_PRODUCT);
```

Comment: not exacly: if I do in your way (put .getActivity inside the onActivityResult method) I have this error: _The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity_

Comment: If this answer worked for you then accept it by clicking on the "right mark" below your answer.